# Why stateless component is re-rendering when props not changing?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am implementing android application using react-native and redux. My container component is updating frequently but props which I am passing to child stateless component not changing, but it still re-render all the time. How can I prevent this re-render? I know that I can use `shouldComponentUpdate`, but then I need to check there all properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why React doesn't do this for you. It would need to check all the properties *and their children (and descendants)*. This could be a lot of work.

If you use React-Redux, just `connect` the component to whatever data it needs and it shouldn't rerender, because Redux makes different assumptions about your data. In particular, it assumes you use immutable objects everywhere, which means it doesn't have to check children (or descendants).

Without React-Redux, you will need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, but if you use immutable data, you can implement a generic function to do a shallow compare and use it in all your components. If you do not use immutable data everywhere, you'll need to either use a deep comparison, or to optimize, implement `shouldComponentUpdate` on a component-by-component basis to do specific checks.

This is a big reason why React-Redux is used.

Comment: Yes I am using `React-Redux` and immutable objects, and connecting container (tab bar view) component to all properties and then I have popup component which is stateless, so should I again connect it to needed properties from the store? Because I think that only container components should be connected.

Comment: You can connect anything, even if `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` return empty objects (implements shallow `shouldComponentUpdate` for you). Essentially, the HOC that `connect` creates becomes the container around the presentational component. Alternatively, you can write a `shouldComponentUpdate` or you can let React sort it out (if it's a small component, there's no need to worry about it).

Answer (score 3):

That's how React works.  If a parent component re-renders, all of its children will re-render, and then React will diff the virtual DOM output and see what actually needs to be updated in the real UI.  This process happens even if the props being passed to a child component haven't changed.  And yes, `shouldComponentUpdate` is the right solution here, but that can't be used with functional components as far as I know, since they have no lifecycle methods.

If you want to prevent re-rendering, you'll probably need to convert those functional components into class components, and either implement `shouldComponentupdate` yourself, or have them extend `React.PureComponent` if you're using React 15.3.

Comment: Component extended from React.PureCompont won't re-render if props won't change?

Comment: Previously, React provided a `PureRenderMixin` to go along with the `React.createClass` way of creating a component. Since those are deprecated, they've added a new `PureComponent` base class, which acts as if it has a shallow-equality-checking `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Got it, thx a lot, just will leave this for others:
`If you determine a specific component is slow after profiling, you may change it to inherit from React.PureComponent which implements shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison.`